# OpenLayers checkbox to remove label

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a problem understanding, I have a dot with vector and a label above it which tells its `$name`.

What I need now, is a checkbox, which hides the label when uncheck it.

```
toggleLabel: function(element) {
            if(element.value == "showLabel"){
                this.viewModel.label.setVisibility(false);
            }
            else {

            }
        },
```

And then in my html I got the following checkbox

```
<input type='checkbox' name='overlay' value='showLabel' id='showLabels' onclick='toggleLabel(this);' autocomplete='off' checked></input>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I do not want to remove the whole layer since I still want the vector to stay(the dot on map) but just hide the label set. Does setvisibility not work on label?

Comment: Please add code, where you define style ($name) - do you use stylemap for layer, add style directly to feature, etc.

Comment: `var defaultStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);

defaultStyle.label = "${" + this.viewModel.label + "}";`

Comment: PS: It's suppose to be two rows but you get the idea.

Comment: And please add code, how you attatch that `defaultStyle` to layer or feature

Comment: `var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": defaultStyle,
                    "select": selectStyle
                });
                haloLayer.styleMap = styleMap;
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that viewModel thing before, but: to hide label, you can just set style's label to empty string; and restore it to display label again.

```
// hide label
haloLayer.styleMap.styles.default.defaultStyle.label = '';
haloLayerLayer.redraw();    

// show label
haloLayer.styleMap.styles.default.defaultStyle.label = "${" + ... + "}";
haloLayerLayer.redraw();
```

Comment: Thanks, im just curious where I set this, on the checkbox call?

Comment: Yes, do it on checkbox call - but I'm not sure about scope and probably you can't use `this` in `this.viewModel.label`